# Linha limite Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-charts

estou enfrentando um problema que não acho a solução rs
Preciso adicionar uma linha limite em meu gráfico, vou colocar uma imagem a baixo de como está agora e como deve ficar. Conseguem me orientar nisto?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['2017', 'Minima', 'Máxima', 'Média'],
        ['Jan', 15, 23, 21],
        ['Fev', 17, 25, 20],
        ['Mar', 18, 30, 22],
        ['Abr', 20, 27, 27],
        ['Mai', 21, 23, 21],
        ['Jun', 23, 28, 26],
        ['Jul', 27, 32, 28],
        ['Ago', 22, 25, 24],
        ['Set', 26, 30, 28],
        ]);

    var options = {

        title: 'Relatório Temperatura Mensal',
        colors: ['#cfcfcf', '#1c1c1c', '#828282'],
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

Atual:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deve ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já. agradeço.

Comment: Vc quer a media? Ou não quer que o grafico cruze a linha vermelha?

Comment: Olá amigo, não, a média já tenho em um gráfico de barra. Oque eu preciso é de uma linha fixada num limite, por exemplo, 23ºC, essa linha vai ficar fixa neste local sempre, dai os gráficos em barra vão cruzar este "limite" e vou conseguir ter alguma visualização no relatório.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes sempre usar este gráfico e usares o "Average" para colocares lá o valor da média média.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
     ['2004/05',  165,      938,         522,             998,           450,      614.6],
     ['2005/06',  135,      1120,        599,             1268,          288,      682],
     ['2006/07',  157,      1167,        587,             807,           397,      623],
     ['2007/08',  139,      1110,        615,             968,           215,      609.4],
     ['2008/09',  136,      691,         629,             1026,          366,      569.6]
  ]);

var options = {
  title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
  vAxis: {title: 'Cups'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
  seriesType: 'bars',
  series: {5: {type: 'line'}}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Adelino, deu super certo ;D